# JAXB: can not read Japanese characters properly

Tags: java, xml, unicode, jaxb

I am having a program which supports internationalisation. I have entries where input is provided in Japanese characters. On exporting that entry in XML, using JAXB, Japanese characters looks fine in the file. Proper character is been exported in the XML file. I am facing issue when unmarshal that XML file to get back data as Java object. I am not get proper unmarshalled value of japanese character.

Here is my marshalling code:

```
OutputStreamWriter outputWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF-8");
JAXB.marshal(xmlobj, outputWriter);
```

Unmarshalling code:

```
InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(xml, "UTF-8");
xmlobj = JAXB.unmarshal(inputReader, <JAVA_CLASS_TO_UNMARSHAL>);
```

The text I am marshalling-unmarshalling is: `説明_1`

It displays correctly on fetching this record and display it to browser, but in case of JAXB unmarshalling incorrect value is displayed. After converting it to HTML compatible code I got value `&#35500;&#26126;_1`, which is actually correct conversion of Japanese characters. And it should appear as proper character on the browser, but it does not do so. It displays as HTML codes `&#35500;&#26126;_1` to the browser.

Any guess where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your string is html escaped value. How using `org.apache StringEscapeUtils` to unescape it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment specified by Wundwin Born has solved the issue. I forgot to unescape string.

Here is the code snippet.

```
org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(xmlString);
```

Comment: That's as I wrote: originally your HTML contained `&amp;#35500;&amp;#26126;` and this call reduced it to `&#35500;&#26126;`

Comment: Right. Agree. But when I was printing that character I have notived that this was not the case. `&` was not been converted as `&amp;`.

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML contains

```
<html>
<body>
&#35500;&#26126;_1<br>
</body>
</html>
```

and good browser like Firefox (I have 31.0) should display  `説明_1`. Can you add the HTML section to your question?

If your browser isn't fit to display these characters, you should see something like ``.

You report that you see `&#35500;&#26126;_1`, which is possible if your HTML text contains

```
&amp;#35500;&amp;#26126;_1<br>
```

which would mean that the transformation to HTML hasn't worked correctly.

Once more: check your HTML code, and how it is produced from the XML.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This leads me to check code again. But it is not the case. Code is as it displays to the HTML. Somehow it is not displaying to correct character. Unescaping as mentioned by Wundwin Born solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using UTF-8 in your HTML Header. Note that just changing the charset in the header won't convert the content — you need to make sure that the content is actually UTF-8 as well.

```
<Meta  http-equiv = "Content-Type"  content = "text / html; charset = UTF-8" >
```

Comment: It is not necessary to define UTF-8 encoding, not with the HTML containing `&#35500;` or similar entities.

Comment: Thanks for the input. But I have already specified this string to HTML page. This is not an issue.